# How can I import eHarmony profiles with PHP?

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

What would be a good method to import profile information from eHarmony with PHP if you have a username and password. I’ve made apps for importing Facebook info to websites using their open graph system, but I don’t know how you would do this for eHarmony, as they don’t have developer features like Facebook.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: This is probably against their terms of service

Comment: I highly doubt this is against their TOS.  You can't invite people to provide you information, then forbid them from accessing their own info.

Comment: Sure you can, @SamDufel.

Answer (score 2):

That is not allowed by their TOS